# Is it perfectly normal to create child windows in the WM_CREATE branch of the WndProc

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it perfectly normal to create child windows in the `WM_CREATE` branch of the `WndProc`?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND w, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            // Create controls
            CreateWindow(
                    L"STATIC",
                    L"Some data:",
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                    10, 10, 100, 20, // x, y, w, h
                    w,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL
            );
            min_area_edit_hwnd = CreateWindow(
                    L"EDIT",
                    L"",
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                    120, 10, 300, 20, // x, y, w, h
                    w,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL
            );
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(w, message, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Is it a common practice to do so?

Comment: Where and when else would you expect to create the window's sub-controls? In response to `WM_DESTROY`?

Comment: @Ken White Maybe in the same place where the `CreateWindow` function for the parent window were called?

Comment: No, because the parent window doesn't exist at that point. Again, what would you expect the `WM_CREATE` message to be intended to be used for? It's for doing the things that you need to do *when you're being created*, which would include *creating child controls*. Find a copy of Petzold's *Programming Windows* book.

Comment: @Ken Actually its perfectly normal to do this after the call to CreateWindow returns. Create them one after the other and then show the main window.

Comment: yes, this absolute normal create child windows on `WM_CREATE`, why at all exist doubt about this ?

Comment: @KenWhite: Actually, it's the other way around. When `CreateWindow` returns, the window is fully constructed. `WM_CREATE` is sent, before `CreateWindow` returns, so at that point the window hasn't been fully constructed. It's still normal to create child windows in a `WM_CREATE` handler.

Comment: @IInspectable: I said it was *perfectly normal to create child windows in a WM_CREATE handler*, and asked where else you would expect to do so. Not sure what you're objecting to here. The handler for WM_CREATE in the WndProc is intended to be where child windows are created; that's why it exists in the first place.

Comment: @KenWhite: I was objecting to your false claim (*"the parent window doesn't exist at that point"*), by explaining, that `CreateWindow` sends a `WM_CREATE` message to the window procedure before it returns. If it is *"perfectly normal to create child windows in a `WM_CREATE` handler"* (which it is), then so is creating child windows right after the parent's `CreateWindow` call returned.

Comment: @IInspectable What he meant was that the window doesn't exist before the call to CreateWindow. But he seemed to imply that because you can't create the children before the parent, you have to create them in WM_CREATE. You can do that, but of course you can also create the children after the parent has been fully created.